# Java, Type mismatch when extending abstract class

Tags: java

I don't understand why data.entrySet() and data.keySet() in the code below are giving me Type Mismatch in eclipse, though I specified the type in both cases in the for loop.

Is this normal or am I missing something that should I take into account when extending an abstract class?

```
import java.util.AbstractSet;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeMap;


abstract class SetDuplicates<K> extends AbstractSet {

    public Map<K, Integer> data;
}

class TreeSetDuplicates<K> extends SetDuplicates {

    public TreeSetDuplicates() {
        data = new TreeMap<K, Integer>();
    }

    public Object first() {
    
    for (Map.Entry<K, Integer> entry : data.entrySet()) {}
    
    for (K element : data.keySet()) {}

    }

    @Override
    public Iterator iterator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

}
```

This is the Eclipse Error:
[image]

Comment: Please show imports and the full error messages. You don't have your own `Set` class nearby, do you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your generics are out of whack. You are getting a warning on the line `class TreeSetDuplicates<K> extends SetDuplicates {`, and when the compiler gives you warnings you don't understand perhaps it is best to focus on those first.

The problem is, *every* mention of `SetDuplicates` needs to carry with it which type you'd like to use for its `<K>` type parameter. Failure to do this makes it a raw type reference, and when you do that, **all generics poof out of existence**. Hence, given that `SetDuplicates` is now raw, so is `data`, and therefore, so is all mention of K or V in any method you care to call on data. Thus, `data.entrySet()` just returns a raw `Map.Entry` object, and you can't just elect to stick the `<K, Integer>` limit on this: A compiler error occurs instead.

Fix the root cause and all problems go away: `class TreeSetDuplicates<K> extends SetDuplicates<K> {}` and off you go.

Let's say you have:

```
class Bar<Z> {}
class Foo<K> extends Bar<K> {}
```

In `class Foo<K> extends Bar<K>`, the *first* use of `<K>` declares a type variable: You are saying: Any mention of this type has a type variable, and we shall call it K.

The *second* use is you *using* this: You're saying: You extend `Bar`, and as with any time you mention Bar anywhere, you need to pick what you want to use for Bar's `Z` type variable. You shall choose K - your own type variable. That's why the letters are not required to be the same letter - they are in your case, which means you're shadowing out the `K` from your superclass with your own K. This is fine - they are the same type after all. But it shows why you need that `<K>` twice: Same syntax, but **utterly** different meaning - first declares, second uses.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. It's been really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It's because generic parameter `K` does not shared between the interface and the class. Change class header as below will resolve the issue.

```java
class TreeSetDuplicates<K extends Object> extends SetDuplicates<K>
```

Comment: `K extends Object` is superfluous; it means the same thing as just `<K>`.